# how to access parent class attribute in base class in python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I am a newbie to python development
I was trying to access parent class attribute in base class but it is giving me the error as

Traceback (most recent call last):
line 41, in 
account.getAccountInfo()
line 24, in getAccountInfo
print("ID " + str(self.cust.custID))
AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'cust'

Here is my code

```
class Customer:
    def __int__(self, custID=00000, cust_name="IJK", address="CABI", contact=9090909090):
        self.custID = custID
        self.cust_name = cust_name
        self.address = address
        self.contact = contact


class Account(Customer):
    def __int__(self, accountID=89839832389, balance=89999999.99):
        self.cust = super.__int__(self)
        self.accountID = accountID
        self.balance = balance

    def getAccountInfo(self):
        print("ID " + str(self.cust.custID))
        print("Name " + str(self.cust.cust_name))
        print("Account ID " + str(self.cust.accountID))

    def deposit(self, balance=2000, savings="true"):
        return self.balance + balance

    def withdraw(self, balance=500):
        return self.balance - balance

    def getBalance(self):
        return self.balance


account = Account()
account.getAccountInfo()
print("Actual balance " + str(account.getBalance()))
account.deposit()
print("Balance after deposit " + str(account.getBalance()))
account.withdraw()
print("Balance after withdraw " + str(account.getBalance()))
```

Comment: 1) `__int__` vs `__init__` 
2)  `self.cust = super.__int__(self)`  init method doesn't return anything
3) Not sure If you are trying to inherit or just need to have Customer object created inside Account

Comment: Himaprason I have to do this thing

Create an account class that inherits from bank class with the following attributes (Use Super () to pass
value to the base class):

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `__int__` should be `__init__` try this one:

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, custID=00000, cust_name="IJK", address="CABI", contact=9090909090):
        self.custID = custID
        self.cust_name = cust_name
        self.address = address
        self.contact = contact


class Account(Customer):
    def __init__(self, accountID=89839832389, balance=89999999.99):
        super().__init__()
        self.accountID = accountID
        self.balance = balance

    def getAccountInfo(self):
        print("ID " + str(self.custID))
        print("Name " + str(self.cust_name))
        print("Account ID " + str(self.accountID))

    def deposit(self, balance=2000, savings="true"):
        return self.balance + balance

    def withdraw(self, balance=500):
        return self.balance - balance

    def getBalance(self):
        return self.balance


account = Account()
account.getAccountInfo()
print("Actual balance " + str(account.getBalance()))
account.deposit()
print("Balance after deposit " + str(account.getBalance()))
account.withdraw()
print("Balance after withdraw " + str(account.getBalance()))
```

Comment: I am getting this error
 print("ID " + str(self.custID))
AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'custID'

Comment: could you share your code which leads to an error?

Comment: I have done the same thing which you have changed

Comment: which version of python are using? mine works under 3.7

Comment: I am using  3.9.1 version